# Attempting to access an s3 yum repo via vagrant results in `Caught exception reading instance data`

Tags: amazon-web-services, yum

We've got a yum repo in s3 (baseurl=https://xxxx.s3.amazonaws.com). When we try to do anything with yum in a Vagrant environment, it throws `[ERROR] Caught exception reading instance data`. Running yum with debug does not provide any additional information.

We can access the repo without problem from our non-vagrant hosts (ie. our ec2 instances

From the vagrant host, we can successfully run `aws s3` commands on the yum repo bucket.

Any thoughts on what might be going on?

Answer (score 0):

The fix for this is is eithe5r (a) make the s3 bucket contents publicly readable via http, which is different than making them readable to the s3 cli, by right clicking the folders and files and selecting "Make public" (not an option for us); or (b) use your aws credentials (access key and secret key) in the `cob` plugin [cob plugin](https://github.com/henrysher/cob).

Option (b) works perfectly for us.